# Cálculo de Idade usando Period

Tags: java, data

Tenho este código abaixo em Java que não compila e não consigo achar o erro. Já fiz as modificações orientadas e o número de erros passou para apenas 1.

O método `calculoIdade` e `validarData` retorna agora o tipo `Period`, mas ao executar ainda apresenta erro de tipo no método `validarData`.

```
import java.time.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Data {

  private int dia, mes, ano;
  String data;

  public void validarData() {

    if (dia > 0 && dia < 32 && mes > 0 && mes < 13 && ano > 0
        && ((mes == 1 || mes == 3 || mes == 5 || mes == 7 || mes == 8 || mes == 10 || mes == 12)
            || ((mes == 4 || mes == 6 || mes == 9 || mes == 11) && dia <= 30)
            || (mes == 2 && (dia <= 29 && ano % 4 == 0 && (ano % 100 != 0 || ano % 400 == 0)) || dia <= 28))) {
      data = "Data válida";
    } else {
      data = "Data inválida";
    }
  }

  public Double calculoIdade(int dia,int mes, int ano) {
        if (validarData()) {
            LocalDate data = LocalDate.of(dia, mes, ano);
            LocalDate now = LocalDate.now();
            if (ano <= 2020) {
                Period diff = Period.between(data, now);
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Quantidade de dias excede o total de dias do mês");
        }
    }

  public void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner leia = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Digite o dia: ");
    dia = leia.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Digite o mês: ");
    mes = leia.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Digite o ano: ");
    ano = leia.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Idade: %d anos, %d meses e %d dias", diff.getYears(), diff.getMonths(), diff.getDays());
    System.out.println(+dia + "/" + mes + "/" + ano + " " + data);
  }

}
```

Após as correções, o código ficou assim:

```
import java.time.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Main {

  private static int dia, mes, ano;
  private String  data;
  private Period diff;
  
  public Period validarData() {

    if (dia > 0 && dia < 32 && mes > 0 && mes < 13 && ano > 0
        && ((mes == 1 || mes == 3 || mes == 5 || mes == 7 || mes == 8 || mes == 10 || mes == 12)
            || ((mes == 4 || mes == 6 || mes == 9 || mes == 11) && dia <= 30)
            || (mes == 2 && (dia <= 29 && ano % 4 == 0 && (ano % 100 != 0 || ano % 400 == 0)) || dia <= 28))) {
      data = "Data válida";
    } else {
      data = "Data inválida";
    }
  }

  public Period calculoIdade(int dia,int mes, int ano) {
        if (validarData()) {
            LocalDate l = LocalDate.of(dia, mes, ano);
            LocalDate now = LocalDate.now();
            if (ano <= 2020) {
                Period diff = Period.between(l, now);
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Quantidade de dias excede o total de dias do mês");
        }
    }

  public void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner leia = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Digite o dia: ");
    dia = leia.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Digite o mês: ");
    mes = leia.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Digite o ano: ");
    ano = leia.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Idade: " + diff.getYears() + " anos, " + diff.getMonths() + " meses, "
                        + diff.getDays() + " dias");
    System.out.println(+dia + "/" + mes + "/" + ano + " " + data);
  }

}
```

Com isto, resultou apenas em 1 erro, conforme abaixo:

```
Main.java:24: error: incompatible types: Period cannot be converted 
to boolean
        if (validarData()) {
                       ^
1 error
```

O que posso fazer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema é que você fez `if (validarData())`, e a condição do `if` deve ser um `boolean`. Mas você declarou que o método `validarData` retorna um `Period`, que não é um `boolean`.

Outro detalhe é que o método  `validarData` não está retornando nada. Se você declarar que ele retorna algo, em algum ponto dele deve ter um `return` para retornar o valor.

Além disso, a variável `diff` que está no `main` não é a mesma que está dentro de `calculoIdade`. Variáveis criadas dentro de um método são locais ao método e não ficam visíveis em outros pontos do programa. E depois que você lê os valores do dia, mês e ano, faltou chamar o método para calcular a idade.

Outro detalhe é que [`LocalDate.of`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#of-int-int-int-) recebe os valores do ano, mês e dia, nessa ordem (você estava passando na ordem errada).

Enfim, uma forma (ainda não ideal, na minha opinião - deixei uma alternativa ao final) de resolver esses problemas seria:

```
static boolean validarData(int dia, int mes, int ano) {
    // em vez de fazer um if gigante, quebre em várias condições
    if (mes < 1 || mes > 12) { // verifica mês inválido
        return false;
    }

    // se chegou aqui, é porque o mês é válido, então agora verifica o dia
    int qtdDias;
    if (mes == 2) {
        if (ano % 4 == 0 && ((ano % 100) != 0 || (ano % 400) == 0)) {
            qtdDias = 29;
        } else {
            qtdDias = 28;
        }
    } else if (mes == 4 || mes == 6 || mes == 9 || mes == 11) {
        qtdDias = 30;
    } else {
        qtdDias = 31;
    }
    return 1 <= dia && dia <= qtdDias;
}

static Period calculoIdade(int dia, int mes, int ano) {
    if (validarData(dia, mes, ano)) {
        if (ano <= 2020) {
            return Period.between(LocalDate.of(ano, mes, dia), LocalDate.now());
        }
    } else {
        // mudei a mensagem porque há mais de um motivo para ser inválida (mês negativo, por exemplo), então deixei a mensagem genérica
        System.out.println("Data inválida");
    }
    // se a data for inválida ou o ano for maior que 2020, retorna null
    return null;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner leia = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Digite o dia: ");
    int dia = leia.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Digite o mês: ");
    int mes = leia.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Digite o ano: ");
    int ano = leia.nextInt();

    Period idade = calculoIdade(dia, mes, ano);
    if (idade != null) { // se não for null, é porque foi calculado
        System.out.printf("Idade: %d anos, %d meses e %d dias\n", idade.getYears(), idade.getMonths(), idade.getDays());
        System.out.printf("%02d/%02d/%d\n", dia, mes, ano); // %02d garante que valores como "2" sejam mostrados como "02"
    }
}
```

---

Mas na verdade não precisa de nada disso. A própria classe `LocalDate` já verifica se a data é válida, lançando uma exceção caso não seja. Então basta usar o que já tem pronto, adicionando apenas o caso especial que verifica se o ano não é maior que 2020 (**se bem que acho melhor verificar simplesmente se a data está no futuro, em vez de fixar um ano**). Para formatar a data, também tem coisas prontas, não precisa reinventar a roda:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner leia = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Digite o dia: ");
    int dia = leia.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Digite o mês: ");
    int mes = leia.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Digite o ano: ");
    int ano = leia.nextInt();

    try {
        LocalDate dataNasc = LocalDate.of(ano, mes, dia);
        LocalDate hoje = LocalDate.now();
        if (dataNasc.isAfter(hoje)) {
            System.out.println("Data de nascimento no futuro, não é possível calcular idade");
        } else {
            Period idade = Period.between(dataNasc, hoje);
            System.out.printf("Idade: %d anos, %d meses e %d dias\n", idade.getYears(), idade.getMonths(), idade.getDays());
            System.out.printf(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/uuuu").format(dataNasc));
        }
    } catch (DateTimeException e) { // se a data for inválida, LocalDate.of lança esta exceção
        System.out.println("Data inválida: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: Prezado @hkotsubo, muito obrigado, agora funcionou.